# Javascript: Want to find all the words in sentence beginning with @

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find all the words beginning with @ in java script

Sentence : "Hey @dinesh, I have mentioned you in @dean vent";

Now using above sentence,  i want to find two words (dinesh and dean) which are beginning with attherate(@). For more convenient you can assume twitter functionality in which any user mentioned other user with @.

If any regular expression or function please tell me

Thanks.

Comment: Use capturing groups `@(\S+)` or `@(\w+)`. Get the names from group index 1. Please do a search before asking this type of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var atmentions = "Hey @dinesh, I have mentioned you in @dean vent".match(/@\w+/g)
// gives ["@dinesh", "@dean"]
```

If you want the user names without '@' you can then convert them like this

```
atmentions.map( function( name ){ return name.substring(1); })
// ["dinesh", "dean"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
function findWords(words) {
    return words.split(" ").filter(function(word) {
        if (word.indexOf("@") === 0) return word
    });
}

var words = findWords("Hey @dinesh, I have mentioned you in @dean vent");
console.log(words); //["@dinesh", "@dean"];
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ofxz74f/

Comment: This actually includes the comma after the first match.  The regex answer is more appropriate as it finds the word boundaries more easily

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as :

```
var sentence = "Hey @dinesh, I have mentioned you in @dean vent",
    result = [];
sentence.split(" ").forEach(function(word) {
     if(word.indexOf("@") == 0) {
          result.push(word);         // or result.push(word.substring(1)) to skip @.
     }
});
console.log(result);    //["@dinesh", @dean"]
```